# Android slide-in slide-out for activity

Tags: android, slide

I have an Android app in which nine of the activities do not load a layout file. Their views are private classes which extend the View class. The activity construct view objects at runtime and uses these objects instead of layout files. The problem that I have is that the views created these activities should slide in and slide out both left and right when switching to other views. I have used a ViewFlipper before but I am unable to one with my need here since view flippers take layout files rather than activities. Is there any chance my problem can be solved without resolving to switching to layout files?

Comment: Be more clear, so you want to do it programatically ?

Comment: Yes. I prefer it programatically done.

Answer (score 8):

Try thoses

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

And in the code when doing StartActivity()

```
overridePendingTransition(R.animator.anim_left, R.animator.anim_right);
```

and then when doing finish()

```
overridePendingTransition(R.animator.anim_left, R.animator.anim_right);
```

Comment: Are they xml files to be placed in res/anim directory? And do I place the overridePending code in the overridden methods of finish() and the constructor?

Comment: Yes one file per animation, and you call the overridePendingTransition when you call finish/startactivity

Comment: This is not clear enough. Which one is right animation aND which one is left?and why there are 4 files? what the names of these files?

Comment: Pleaseyou name the files as you want.These are horizontal animations so, you need to look at "delta x". This value shows the position of your view compared with the position of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

```
this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

write it just below of your Intent.

Comment: Thanks but does it mean that I don't have to define an animation file?