# LayoutTransition custom the transition

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, transition

I try to set a custom animation between 2 layouts.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    View menu = null;
    ViewGroup parent = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_models);

        //initialize the container and his parent
        menu = findViewById(R.id.menu_model);
        parent = (ViewGroup) menu.getParent();

        //set transition
        LayoutTransition lt = new LayoutTransition();
        lt.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
        parent.setLayoutTransition(lt);

        restoreMenu(null);
    }

    //display second menu
    public void changeMenu(View view) {

        int index = parent.indexOfChild(menu);
        View old = menu;
        menu = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_2, parent, false);
        parent.addView(menu, index);
        parent.removeView(old);
    }

    //display first menu
    public void restoreMenu(View view) {

        int index = parent.indexOfChild(menu);
        View old = menu;
        menu = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_1, parent, false);
        parent.addView(menu, index);
        parent.removeView(old);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using `LayoutTransition` with the `LayoutTransition.CHANGING` effect.
But I want it looks like this:

My old menu is leaving to the left and my new menu is coming from the right.

Do you have any ideas how I could do that ? Does the `LayoutTransition` can do that ?

Comment: My last post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852481/android-slide-in-slide-out-for-activity/17852714#17852714

Comment: Thanks but it's used between 2 activities and I'm looking for an animation between 2 views

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Define the slide-in and slide-out animations with `TranslateAnimation` and then use

```
overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)
```

this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)

Comment: thanks but I am not using startActivity() It's a view translation

Comment: then assign seperate TranslateAnimation to each layouts?