# Slider animation between activities

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I have to implement a simple animation between 2 activities: I've already implemented some simple animations, but last one is a little bit more difficult to realize.

The animation should act like this: Activity A (on screen) slides from YDelta = 0 to Ydelta = -100%. In the meantime, Activity B is already in its final position (it doesn't move, no translation needed...) and it's slowly showed.... Like a courtain...

I'tried in this bad way:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_anim, R.anim.slide_to_top);
```

no_anim:

```
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="2000"/>
```

slide_to_top:

```
 <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="2000"/>
```

The result is not correct: Activity B (that is binded to no_anim) is immediatly showed on the screen, and so Activity A simply disappear...

How can I solve my problem?

TY and BR!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem then I found, (as the [*z-order*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in css) there is a really great parameter for the animations: [`android:zAdjustment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3azAdjustment): *"allows for an adjustment of the **Z ordering** of the content being animated for the duration of the animation"*. You will able to display the next activity **behind** the previous activity. You have 3 possible values:

> - **normal:** default value equals to *0*
> - **bottom:** displayed in *-1*; value to be behind
> - **top:** value for *1*; displayed at the top

Therefore, the `slide_to_top.xml`:

```
<translate 
    android:zAdjustment="top"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

Also you don't need to set a `no_anim` animation because your next activity will have the default value `0` and your previous activity will have `+1`. Just tested and it works like a charm, really! Then, the method:

```
overridePendingTransition(0,R.anim.slide_to_top);
```

I really hope you found a way to resolve this. However, this solution might help someone which wants the same behaviour than yours.

Answer (score 0):

See my post [Android slide-in slide-out for activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852481/android-slide-in-slide-out-for-activity/17852714#17852714)

You need to create an animation right to left and left to right for both views from and to...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response: but in your example, both activities move from a direction to another. In my case, only the exit activity has a real animation (it moves from Ydelta = 0 to YDelta = -100p), while activity B doesn't move! It's already in its final position and it's slowly showed. I don't want it to appear from the bottom of the screen. Like a courtain!

Comment: You can use ydelta instead of xdelta, and in the method overridependingtransition you only provide the transitions for the only view you want to animate ?