# Swipe Activity with smooth animation

Tags: android, swipe

I am trying to solve this problem...

Structure is-

```
[1]<---->[2]<-------->[3]<-------->[4]
```

Where [ ]=Activity...(Need-smooth animation with swipe view)
what I don't need -----> blinks and Backward Stacks while press back on Android device...

Activity 1 swipes for 2 and further 3 for 4 but it gives a blink instead of swipe...

Here is the code...

```
  public ActivitySwipeDetector(SwipeInterface activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void onRightToLeftSwipe(View v){
    Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
    activity.right2left(v);
}

public void onLeftToRightSwipe(View v){
    Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
    activity.left2right(v);
}

public void onTopToBottomSwipe(View v){
    Log.i(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
    activity.top2bottom(v);
}

public void onBottomToTopSwipe(View v){
    Log.i(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
    activity.bottom2top(v);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        downX = event.getX();
        downY = event.getY();
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        upX = event.getX();
        upY = event.getY();

        float deltaX = downX - upX;
        float deltaY = downY - upY;

        // swipe horizontal?
        if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
            // left or right
            if(deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(v); return true; }
            if(deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(v); return true; }
        }
        else {
            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
        }

        // swipe vertical?
        if(Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE){
            // top or down
            if(deltaY < 0) { this.onTopToBottomSwipe(v); return true; }
            if(deltaY > 0) { this.onBottomToTopSwipe(v); return true; }
        }
        else {
            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least       " + MIN_DISTANCE);
            v.performClick();
        }
    }
    }
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Avijit, are you running for "Copy Editor" Badge ?

Comment: Is this of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852481/android-slide-in-slide-out-for-activity/17852714#17852714

Comment: use view-pager to done this thing easily.

Comment: use fragments instead of activitys! Fragments are kept in memory if so specified so no blinking will occur

Comment: @user3264399 I am just editing the post to make it more visualised.

Comment: @Avijit Ok I believe you, But let other user give fair chance. If you edit all the post then what we will do ?

Comment: @user3264399 So its your issue that you didn't get some chance to edit  some of the post :) . Well, You will get the chance rightly.

Comment: Can Any one solve this issue instead of suggesting me to use Fragment...(Although i am also following fragments so i need solution of this question not a reference As everyone is giving :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use fragments instead of Activities. What you want is easily done with a viewpager. I used this tutorial the first time I used a viewpager:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

And here is the official link:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Hope this helps!